Google App Script Copy New Date +7 Day not work
I'm trying to get a new Date with +7 day from the Google sheet and put in new Cell but it's not working for before month and after the month as present.
var current_date = datasheet.getRange(j,1).getValue();
      var next_date =  new Date();
      next_date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
      next_date.setDate(current_date.getDate()+7);
      ssTimeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
      datasheet.getRange(lastRow,1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(next_date, ssTimeZone, 'dd.MM.yyyy'));

                                                            

When I try for July it gives me my +7 day of Oct and if I try December it will also give Oct date
This Date to +7 Day
05.05.2024
03.05.2024
07.05.2024

After Run Script Result Give
12.10.2024
10.10.2024
14.10.2024


When you use new Date() you are getting a date in October.  You are getting the date of current_date say 3 adding 7 and setting the October date to 10.  If you want to get the date 7 days from current_date simply add 7 to it. current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate()+7)

@TheWizEd thx man this was my fault ...

It would probably be easier to adjust those dates using plain vanilla spreadsheet formulas, but because the Sheets–Apps Script automatically converts dates between the two, something like this should be enough in Apps Script:
  const date = datasheet.getRange(j, 1).getValue();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
  datasheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(date);

See:

Working with date and time values in Google Sheets

Working with Dates and Times in Apps Script


